# How to use hook_form_alter to change the cancel link

Tags: forms

I am trying to accomplish a very simple thing - changing the cancel link in the invite_withdraw_form function - with no success. The function is in this file http://cgit.drupalcode.org/invite/tree/includes/invite.pages.inc#n120 So my custom function looks likes this now:

```
function my_custom_module_form_invite_withdraw_form_alter($form, &$form_state) {
  debug($form['actions']['cancel']);
  $uid = $form['invite']['#value']->uid;
  $cancel = 'user/'.$uid.'/invites/pending';
  $form['actions']['cancel'] = array(
    '#type' => 'link',
    '#title' => 'Cancel',
    '#href' => $cancel,
    '#options' => array ('path' => $cancel),
  );
  debug($form['actions']['cancel']);
}
```

It hooks successfully, because I see output of two debugs, the second of which confirms the array has changed from:

```
array (
  '#type' => 'link',
  '#title' => 'Cancel',
  '#href' => '<front>',
  '#options' => 
  array (
    'path' => '<front>',
  ),
)
```

to

```
array (
  '#type' => 'link',
  '#title' => 'Cancel',
  '#href' => 'user/1/invites/pending',
  '#options' => 
  array (
    'path' => 'user/1/invites/pending',
  ),
)
```

but for some reason when I click the Cancel button it keeps redirecting me to the front page. What I am doing wrong and what is the right code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're just missing an ampersand (&) in front of $form in the first line of your code.

Comment: OMG, I knew it was so simple. Thank you very much, Anne!